# Google SketchUp API

Tags: c++, ruby, sketchup

let's say hypothetically I wanted to create an application that manipulates Google SketchUp files. The GS (Google SketchUp) API is written in Ruby and also has another API specifically used for reading/writing .skp (SketchUp files) that is written in [C++](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/downloadsdksubmit.html). The only problem is that this C++ API was created by the original SketchUp team (before acquisition by Google) and it is no longer being updated or maintained.

So, would anyone know if the Ruby API will allow you to create plug-ins or manipulate the .skp file structure? Or has anyone had experience with the the C++ SDK and can say with confidence that it is worth using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ruby API can only modify the model that's open in SketchUp.

To manipulate .skp files you will have to use the C++ SDK. And the SDK is updated I believe to keep up with the formats of SketchUp as they update it. I know that there are people who use it to create exporters etc.

I think there might be more C++ SDK related discussions over at the Google Groups than at SketchUcation, but you might have some luck finding people with experience over at both sites.

http://groups.google.com/group/google-sketchup-developers?pli=1

http://forums.sketchucation.com/viewforum.php?f=180

Comment: So can the SDK modify the model that's open in SketchUp as well, or can it only do import/export of .skp files? I'm just learning to write SketchUp plugins and haven't been able to find a clear answer to that on either the google groups or sketchucation sites.

Comment: The C++ SDK has now been replaced by a new C API. But both of these only read and write files. They do not act on the live move - only the Ruby API does that.